# How to get this jQuery script to run individually on more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if the title is correct. I can't seem to express this problem properly in words!

I have the following text fields in my HTML that I'm trying to limit the number of characters that can be entered into:

```
<div class="limited limit-200">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="_je_industries_desc">Industry Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <textarea class="large-text" name="industries_desc" id="industries_desc" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
        <p id="industries_desc_description" class="description">Put a short description of this industry.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="limited limit-100">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="_je_seo_description">Meta Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <textarea class="large-text" name="seo_description" id="seo_description" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
        <p id="seo_description_description" class="description">Put a short description of the content of this page.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery so far.
It gets the character limit from the class name in the HTML `limit-200` for example. Then calculates the amount of characters left as you type and outputs the remaining characters under the textarea.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.limited').each(function() {
        // Get the class names of any element that has the class .limited
        var className = jQuery(this).attr('class');

        // Use regex to capture the character limit class (limit-#)
        var limit = className.match(/[?:limit-](\d+)/);

        // Set the limit var to the match from the regex
        var limit = limit[1];

        // Calculate the number of characters that are still available (limit - characters in field)
        var chars_left = limit - jQuery('textarea', this).val().length;

        //alert(chars_left);

        // Attach an event handler to each textarea with the class .limited
        jQuery('textarea', this).on('keyup', function() {
            var maxchar = limit;
            var cnt = jQuery(this).val().length;
            var remainingchar = maxchar - cnt;
            if(remainingchar < 0){
                jQuery('#limit-counter span').html('<strong>0</strong>');
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().slice(0, limit));
            } else {
                jQuery('#limit-counter span').html('<strong>' + remainingchar + '</strong>');
            }
        });

        // Display number of characters left
        jQuery('textarea', this).after('<span id="limit-counter">Remaining characters: <span><strong>' + chars_left + '</strong></span></span>');
    });
});
```

This works great for a single textarea but if I have more than one and type in one of the textareas the other textarea updates its counter with the same value as the one I'm typing in.

Could someone please help me spot what I'm doing wrong? Hopefully I'm just missing something simple somewhere!

Thanks!

Comment: Is maxlength html attribute not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added this to a fiddle and done the modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/KQKnN/

```
    var $textarea=jQuery(this).find('textarea');
    var uniqueId= $textarea.attr('id');
```

Trouble here that your limit-counter has to be unique, you can't have two elements with the same id on one page.

```
        if(remainingchar < 0){
            jQuery('#limit-counter-'+uniqueId+' span').html('<strong>0</strong>');
            jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().slice(0, limit));
        } else {
            jQuery('#limit-counter-'+uniqueId+' span').html('<strong>' + remainingchar + '</strong>');
    // .....

    $textarea.after('<span id="limit-counter-'+uniqueId+'">Remaining characters: <span><strong>' + chars_left + '</strong></span></span>');
```

I also added the textarea to a cached selector - you'll get better performance because of this but it's totally optional.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work here (Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 16.0).

Comment: Thanks @popvilasp this works perfectly! I'm not sure why I didn't see I had an id in there!! I've been modifying this script from a site I did a couple of years ago and it was made for a specific field then hence the id! I really like your solution so thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche there are a few typos in the jsfiddle but once those are sorted it works perfectly. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KQKnN/1/ so I've still marked popvilasp's answer as the solution.

Comment: sorry for the typos, was in a rush, but wanted to help :))

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this *a lot*. Start by just putting the maximum restraint in a `maxlength` attribute:

```
<textarea name="seo_description" maxlength="100"></textarea>
```

Then, select all `textarea`s that have a `maxlength` attribute, and loop through them:

```
$('textarea[maxlength]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        limit = $this.attr('maxlength'),
        $counter = $('<span class="limit-counter">Remaining characters: <strong></strong></span>')
                    .insertAfter(this).find('strong');

    $this.on('keyup', function() {
        $counter.text( limit - $this.val().length );
    })
    .trigger('keyup');
});
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/U4Mk6/

Comment: Very nice solution! At the moment I don't have the ability to add the maxlength attribute to the HTML. I'll change some of the code that controls the text areas though so I can use this eventually as it's so much more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes - regardless of whether you use `maxlength`, the idea is the same: you store the counter element in a local variable, and only update its value.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, thanks! I'll play around with this. It's beautiful code compared to my crude attempt.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your specific problem goes, I think this line and the one within the `else` is the culprit:

```
jQuery('#limit-counter span').html('<strong>0</strong>');
```

which should be:

```
jQuery('#limit-counter span', this).html('<strong>0</strong>');
```

Does this help?